# Highcharts JS: How do I decrease the spacing between Y values?

Tags: highcharts

I want my bar chart to look like this:

[image]

But currently the spacing between my bars is too wide:

[image]

I tried looking up the docs but I don't know what the terminology is and couldn't find it. Which options would I pass to shrink the amount of spacing between the y values?

Comment: You can align datalabels by setting parameter "align". Example http://jsfiddle.net/c2bhotsv/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use **`pointPadding`** and **`groupPadding`**. **groupPadding** is the padding between each value groups, in x axis units. **pointPadding** is the padding between each column or bar, in x axis units:

```
plotOptions: {
        series: {
            pointPadding: 0.05,
            groupPadding: 0.05,
        }
}
```

Here's a [**DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/84eg1635/).

Comment: Nice, but with only 3 y values, each bar is really fat (in your demo, if you only use Jan, Feb, March and the first 3 y values, you'll see what I mean). I want to specify `pointWidth: 40`. Is there a way to do this with what you just posted?

Comment: **pointWidth** overrides **pointPadding** and **groupPadding** http://api.highcharts.com/highcharts#plotOptions.column.pointWidth If you know the whole width of the chart and you want the exact width of every column to be this, then it's best to use `pointWidth`. But if you don't, the use of `pointPadding` and `groupPadding` would be more rational.

Comment: I ended up adjusting the `height` of the chart so that it was smaller. that + `pointWidth: 40` worked in having less padding + set bar widths. thanks